# Как просматривать и вносить изменения в SQLite базу данных android приложения?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, android-sqlite

По пути `/data/data/[название_пакета]/databases/` находятся 3 файла `database`, `database-shm` и `database-wal`.
Если я хочу внести изменения в базу данных мобильного приложения (к примеру, добавить данные), но не хочу создавать внутри самого приложения функционал, направленный на эти действия, что мне нужно сделать с этими файлами?
Другими словами, как мне просмотреть и отредактировать SQLite базу данных android приложения?

С помощью какой программы их открывать?

Как и в какие конкретно из этих 3 файлов нужно вносить изменения?

Comment: если у Вас есть доступ к файлам БД то открывайте их подходящим менеджером БД, редактируйте и возвращайте на Android устройство

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak, с поиском подходящего инструмента тоже, пока что, проблема, пробовал использовать Sqlitebrowser, нажал на кнопку "Открыть базу данных", он эти файлы просто не увидел (по крайней мере в режиме "Файлы SQLite базы данных (*.db, *.sqlite, *.sqlite3, *.db3)") (может быть, конечно, я что-то делаю не так), открываю в Firefox SQLite Manager, в одном случае пишет "no such table: NA", в другом "file is not a database"

Comment: Открыть базу данных и режим "все файлы", и выбираете из трех конкретно database. Еще drag-n-drop ом можно файл в окно перенести. Расширение файла может быть любым, отсутствие расширения, слишком рано стало для вас препятствием... речь о https://sqlitebrowser.org/